# Show that the ideal $ (2, 1 + \sqrt{-7} ) $ in $ \mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{-7} ] $ is not principal

Tags: ring-theory

Show that the ideal $ I =  (2, 1 + \sqrt{-7} ) $ in $ \mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{-7} ] $ is not principal.

My thoughts so far:

Work by contradiction. Assume that $ I $ is principal, i.e. that it is generated by some element $ z = a + b\sqrt{-7} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}] $. I'm really not sure what to consider though - I can't really 'see' what $ I $ looks like.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32577/show-that-a-specific-ideal-is-not-principal/32585#32585) can help you since it is a similar problem.

Comment: Let me point out that the class number of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ is 1, so the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID.  However, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ is only an order of conductor $2$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Answer (score 9):

Put $\rm\, w = 1\!+\!\sqrt{-7}.\,$ By norms $2\,$ is *irreducible* so, if principal $\rm\,\color{#c00}{ (2,w) = (1)}\ $ [not $(2)$ by $\rm\,2\nmid w$]

so $\rm\ 2\mid 2w,\,ww'\Rightarrow\ 2\mid (2w',ww') = \color{#c00}{(2,w)}(w') =  (w'),\ $ so $\rm\ 2\mid w',\ $ contradiction. $\ \, $ QED

This is a special case of the fact that the failure of an irreducible element to be prime (or a failure of Euclid's Lemma) immediately yields a nonexistent gcd and nonprincipal ideal - see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37085/integral-domain-with-two-elements-that-do-not-have-a-gcd/37089#37089)

Comment: When you write $w'$ you mean the conjugated?

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Yes, Galois should know that! $\ \ $

Comment: @user1952009 If you tell me what you do not understand then I will be happy to elaborate. Answers are written at different levels to accommodate readers at different levels.

Comment: @user1952009 I offer to help you understand it and you replied with a downvote. Sheesh. You don't seem to be very sincere about desiring to understand it. That's your loss.

Comment: I don't care understanding what you wrote, I know it is trivial, and that's the problem : you can't explain clearly something trivial (see Arturo Magidin's answer)

Comment: As you want, but the downvote is deserved, for what I took time to explain

Comment: I still don't understand why you think $(2,w) \ne (2)$ and $(2,w) \ne (1)$. You have a big problem of deduction

Comment: @user1952009  $\ $ Suppose it's principal $\,(2,w) = (a).\,$ Then $\,a\mid 2.\,$ Since $2$ is irreducible, $\,a\,$ is associate to $\,2\,$ or $\,1,\,$ i.e. $\,(a) = (1)\,$  or $\,(a) = (2).\,$ But $\,(2,w)=(a)=(2)\,\Rightarrow\, 2\mid w,\,$ contra $\,w/2\not\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-7}].\,$ Thus $\,(2,w)=(a)= (1).\,$ The rest of the proof is essentially  [Euclid's Lemma in ideal form](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242), as explained in [the linked answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37085/integral-domain-with-two-elements-that-do-not-have-a-gcd/37089#37089)

Comment: @reuns (formerly user1952009 ) Re-reading this a few years later, I still have no idea what you think "you explained", nor if the trivial argument in my prior comment is what you thought I "could not explain". Nor do I see any "big problem with deduction". Your remarks are among the most puzzling I've ever received on this site.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a picture of the elements of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-7}]$ (in green) embedded into the plane in such a way that their distance form the origin (blue) is equal to their norm. The ideal is drawn on top in purple.

[image: lattices]

Now here are some pictures of principal ideas.

$$(5)$$

[image: lattice]

$$(3 - \sqrt{-7})$$

[image: lattice]

$$(1 - 2\sqrt{-3})$$

[image: lattice]

$$(1 + \sqrt{-7})$$

[image: lattice]

$$(1+3\sqrt{-7},10+2\sqrt{-7})$$

[image: lattice]

You could probably see immediately that last one is not a principal ideal! The density of points is too strong for it to be principal. I am not sure how to turn this "density" concept into mathematical proof but I'm sure it can be done.

I the gnuplot command used

```
plot './lattice.txt' with points pointsize 0.4 pt 20 lt 2 notitle, './lattice2.txt' with points pointsize 0.5 pt 20 lt 4, './origin.txt' with points pointsize 0.5 pt 20
```

to draw these.

Comment: the inverse of the density is the size of the quotient ring A/I, and it's the norm of the ideal I. So you are using a norm argument.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the map $N\colon\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by
$$N(a+b\sqrt{-7}) = a^2+7b^2.$$
This map is multiplicative, so if $z\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ divides $2$, then $N(z)$ divides $N(2) = 4$. So $N(z)=1$, $N(z)=2$, or $N(z)=4$. Check the possibilities, and see if any of them divides $1+\sqrt{-7}$; those are your possible generators (note that the ideal $(2,1+\sqrt{-7})$ is principal if and only if $(2,1+\sqrt{-7})=(z)$ for some $z$, which implies that $z$ divides both $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-7}$).  Not check to see if any of the possible generators are actually generators.

The map $N$ is called the "norm map". It is given by taking an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$, and multiplying all its images under the different embeddings of its field of fractions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ into $\mathbb{C}$; it is a standard tool for studying divisibility and ideals in orders, such as $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$.

Comment: Thanks. If $ N(\alpha) = 1 $, we are forced to have $ \alpha = 1 $. The ideal generated by $ \alpha $ is therefore the whole ring. Why can't this be the case?

Comment: @user938272: Because $(2,1+\sqrt{-7})$ is not the entire ring. Verify that the square of any element in that ideal is necessarily a multiple of $2$, so the ideal cannot contain $1$.

Comment: @user938272: Alternatively, notice that $(2,1+\sqrt{-7})^2 = (4,2+2\sqrt{-7},-6+2\sqrt{-7})$, so every element of the square of the ideal is a multiple of $2$, hence we cannot have $(2,1+\sqrt{-7}) = (1)$. Also: $N(\alpha)=1$ implies $\alpha=\pm 1$, and not only $\alpha=1$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove this note that $1 \not \in I$ so $I \not = (1)$. Then suppose $I = (\alpha)$, that implies that $\alpha = 2$ or $\alpha = 1 + \sqrt{-7}$ since those are both irreducibles, but neither of them can hold since one irreducible is not a multiple of another.

Comment: You can't simply claim $\: I\ne 1\:$ That requires proof. Indeed, it's the only nontrivial part of the proof.