# Geometric understanding of principal/non-principal ideals

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

A number field $K$ with the $r$ embeddings into $\mathbb R$ and $2s$ pairs of conjugate embeddings into $\mathbb C$ can put into ring homomorphism with the product of rings $\mathbb R^r \times \mathbb C^s$, ideals of the ring of integers of $K$ are mapped to lattices in this space.

Are there any geometric criteria to tell the difference between a principal ideal and non-principal ones? Can we somehow use the geometry of these lattices to find the non-principal ideals? To find all nonprime atoms?

I got this question from the graphics [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37468/show-that-the-ideal-2-1-sqrt-7-in-mathbbz-sqrt-7-is-not/37487#37487).